# Rails CanCan Simple_form association issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, simple-form

Why doesen't cancan stop the dept_tech role from creating users in detpartments where the dept_tech role has no access?

I am using cancan for autorization and simple_form for views.
I have a user model and a department model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
  ...
end

class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :departments
  ...
end
```

I also have an abilities model

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    Rails.logger.debug {" >>>>>>> user id: #{user.id} ......
    if user.role? :admin
     ...
    elseif user.role? :dept_tech
      Rails.logger.debug {" >>>>>>> role 6 ......
      can :manage, User, :department_id => user.department_id
      can :read, Department, :id => user.department_id
      Rails.logger.debug {" >>>>>>> user.department: #{user.department_id}}
    end
  end
 end
```

and user controller:

```
load_and_authorize_resource
...
def new

  respond_to do |format|
    Rails.logger.debug {" >>>> here"}
    format.html # new.html.erb
  end
  Rails.logger.debug {" >>>> there"}
end
...
```

There is also a

```
load_and_authorize_resource
```

in the department controller.

and a _form view helper using simple_form

```
<% simple_form_for @user, :html => {class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  Rails.logger.debug {" >>>> view"}
  <%= f.association :department %>
  ....
<% end %>
```

This works well, a dept_tech can only do index and show actions for department. It also works well for the index, show action for users. However when the new action on users is performed the collection_select for department shows all departments, not only the department of the dept_tech.

The thinking is the dept_tech can only create (manage) users of his own department.

This is the log, that shows that select is used without where on the department select, and it is done in the view.

```
Started GET "/users/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-05 13:57:58 +0200
[2012-06-05 13:57:58 +0200] Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
[2012-06-05 13:57:58 +0200]   User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
[2012-06-05 13:57:58 +0200]  >>>> User id: 2, User role: ["dept_tech"], roles_mask: 64
[2012-06-05 13:57:58 +0200]  >>>> Role 6
[2012-06-05 13:57:58 +0200]  >>>> user.department: 2
[2012-06-05 13:57:58 +0200]  >>>> here
[2012-06-05 13:57:58 +0200]  >>>> view
[2012-06-05 13:57:58 +0200]   Department Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "departments".* FROM "departments" 
[2012-06-05 13:57:58 +0200]   Rendered users/_form.html.erb (45.7ms)
[2012-06-05 13:57:58 +0200]   Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (46.5ms)
[2012-06-05 13:57:58 +0200]  >>>> there
[2012-06-05 13:57:58 +0200] Completed 200 OK in 63ms (Views: 56.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.8ms)
```

The log shows that not surprisingly the SQL gets called in the view. Is this a simple_form issue? How to solve?